# How to keep UI responsive when CPU load is 100% (Mainly using C++ and Qt)?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, freeze

I'm facing a problem between where I need to keep my UI (and the full OS) responsive in multi-threaded application.

I'm developing an application (c++ and Qt based) which received and transform lot of video frame from multiple stream at the same time.

Each stream is retrieved, transformed and rendered in its own separate worker thread (using DirectX). That means I'm not using the default GUI thread to render the frame.

On a powerful computer I have no problem because the cpu can process all data and keep time for the GUI thread to process user request. But on a old computer, it doesn't work, the CPU is used at 100% to process my data, and UI is lagging, it may takes 10 seconds before a button click become processed.

I would like to keep my UI responsive. In fact, I want my worker thread works only if there is no others action to do. I tried to change the worker thread priority to low, but it doesn't work. I also tried a sleep(10) in the worker thread, but because I can have lots of threads, they don't fall in sleep at the same time, so it's not working either.

What is the best way to keep an UI responsive in that case (whatever the toolkit use)?

Comment: It sounds like you are just creating too many threads.

Comment: you should make worker threads lower priority than thread(s) that handle UI requests

Comment: "I tried to change the worker thread priority to low, but it doesn't work." - obviously that's the kind of suggestion your question will solicit (and Ivor has provided), so SHOW YOUR CODE AND DESCRIBE WHAT WENT WRONG.  Separately, for real time video display it's normal to add some lines of code to measure time and if you're not rendering frames fast enough, start rendering less concurrently - dropping some frames; alternatively do something to reduce resolution or rendering quality.

Comment: Are you running out of memory? That kind of response time feels more like memory is being paged to and from disk, unless you've got a truly insane number of worker threads.

Comment: Sleep(0) should be enough, if it does not work then you might want to look at Fibers, I never used them but they allow for more execution control

Comment: If lowering the priority of the worker threads don't fix the problem and you don't start more of them than you have cpu cores then the user is competing with kernel threads.  Video driver typically.  And will always lose.

Comment: An ugly hack would be to occasionally explicitly tell Qt to process all the waiting events using [processEvents()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents). It's not a true solution (therefor just a comment), but could keep your UI slightly more responsive.

Comment: Thank you for all your comment!

That true, processEvents help my GUI to be more responsive, but not the for OS.

This not a memory problem. In fact, i have only frame per view in memory, so this not to big, and i keep lot of ram available.

Comment: I tried also to change main thread priority but it doesn't works.

Sorry, i can't share my code, this is too big. I just can say that my thread received the current frame data from HTTP (libcurl), it decode the frame, transform (rescale, convert) it and render it (using DirectX). When done, i got the next current frame. So, some frame may be skipped if the last rendering takes too much time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can't add my comments on above list so I've to add my few cents here:

- if You want OS more responsive then make sure you don't consume too much RAM and start process in lower priority - afaik thread priorities are taken into account only when OS has to decide which thread from process should be run, but whole process still works on 100% cpu when other processes from system are taken into account
- make sure not to run too many threads, good solution is to create as many threads that use 100% cpu as there are cores, if you want more then use multitasking techniques

One thing to check - how You do video display? Do you make sure your display rate (data from streams) matches display card's refresh rate? When You have data to display do You notify main thread about need to update screen (better solution) or You force frame display from each thread (bad solution)?

Comment: most of OS locking is because of too much data being displayed at same time or too much data being read/written

Comment: Ok, thank you all, i feel stupid, but I found the problem! Actually, it was just a bug in my application. I used process explorer to track my threads priorities, and i found it's wasn't correctly set! But set the priority was the solution!